Trouble in device tree source compile
I was tring to compile a dts file and tried command with make
dtc -I dts -O dtb -@ -I /home/pi/rpisrc/linux/arch/arm64/boot/dts -o sss.dtb sss.dts

but it through out an error like
FATAL ERROR: Unknown input format: /home/pi/rpisrc/linux/arch/arm64/boot/dts.

What format does flag -I expect? I'm sure the directory is exist. What's the problem?
For details this is my Makefile below
#Makefile for compiling a single device tree source file


#dts name without extend

DTS_NAME = sss

#Output dir

OUTPUT_DIR = ./output

#cross compile tool chain

CROSS_COMPILE = DTC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)dtc

#Options

#generate dtb, enable symbols, overlays

DTC_FLAGS = -I dts -O dtb -@

#Linux kernel device tree include path

LINUX_KERNEL_DIR = /home/pi/rpisrc/linux

INCLUDE_PATH = -I $(LINUX_KERNEL_DIR)/arch/arm64/boot/dts

#Target file

DTB_FILE = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(DTS_NAME).dtb

#Default

all: $(DTB_FILE)

#Command

$(DTB_FILE): $(DTS_NAME).dts

mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR)

$(DTC) $(DTC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATH) -o $@ $<

$(info DTC command: $(DTC) $(DTC_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATH) -o $@ $\<)

#Clean

clean: rm -rf $(OUTPUT_DIR)

.PHONY: all clean


Why did you remove the original question? There were comments that pointed out to the problems in your case.

Option -I (uppercase) denotes an input format. Option -i (lowercase) denotes include path. It seems you wanted to use -i option with /home/pi/rpisrc/linux/arch/arm64/boot/dts parameter.

@0andriy Thank you so much for your comment! I reposted my issue because someone voted to close my question but I want my question remain open. And also I can't figure out my problem from the comments link you shared, maybe I need to find some other solutions.

@Tsyvarev  That's it! /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~  It works! Really a stupid mistake, I just begin to learn this, you saved me. Thank you!
